# Error message when trying to use Open Function call

Tags: c, system-calls, xv6

As part of my homework, I need to create a small c program for XV6.  This program has to create a file, write to it, then close it.

When I try and compile the xv6 with my file I am receiving two error message.

```
HWC2.c:13:82: error: ‘O_CREAT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 fd = open("/home/kyle/Desktop/Projects/'Assignment 2'/xv6/Tom.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
                                                                              ^
HWC2.c:13:14: error: called object ‘open’ is not a function or function pointer
 fd = open("/home/kyle/Desktop/Projects/'Assignment 2'/xv6/Tom.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
```

I'm new to C programming so I'm limited to what I can find with a google search and nothing there has helped.  Instead, of `O_CREAT` I did try just using write.

```
#include "types.h"
#include "stat.h"
#include "user.h"

int open;
int fd;

int main (void)
{

    printf(1,"My Name\n");
    fd = open("/home/kyle/Desktop/Projects/Assignment 2/xv6/Tom.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT);

    write(fd, "1 2 3 4", 7);
    close(fd);

}
```

I need it to compile,  print my name, create the file, write to the file, then save and close the file

Comment: You forget to `#include "fcntl.h"`. And in this file, it's `O_CREATE` not `O_CREAT`

Comment: Thank you.  I've added and made it further in the compiling,  but it's having a problem with the fcntl.h

In file included from /usr/include/fcntl.h:25:0, from HW2.c:4:
/usr/include/features.h:424:25: fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
 #  include <sys/cdefs.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'HW2.o' failed
make: *** [HW2.o] Error 1

I've checked the sys folder and the file is there.

Comment: I'm not sure you're taking the good header. Look at  fcntl.h info xv6 repo: It's only a few lines long. How is configured your compilation chain?

Comment: I was able to get it fixed.  Thank you for your help.  I had <>  when I should have done what you posted and used "" around fcntl.h.

Answer (score 0):

Try including

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

For printing name you could try:

```
printf("%s\n", "My Name");
```